# Output of VBA macro insert to new booksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code is working perfectly. But I am trying to solve how output insert automatically to the new sheet with name "result". Has anybody know how deal with my problem?

```
Sub macronew()
Dim NumberOfCompany As Integer
Dim column As Integer
Dim year As Integer
Do
year = 2004
For column = 20 To 22
    For NumberOfCompany = 1 To 10
    Range("N2").Activate
    ActiveCell = year
    Range("N3") = NumberOfCompany
    SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
    If SolverSolve(UserFinish:=True) = 4 Or SolverSolve(UserFinish:=True) = 5 Then
    Cells(NumberOfCompany + 1, column) = "N/A"
    Else
    Range("L3").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Cells(NumberOfCompany + 1, column).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End If
    Next NumberOfCompany
year = year + 1
Next column
Loop Until year > 2006
End Sub
```

Comment: What output? Do you already have a sheet named "Result"?

Comment: No, I dont. It doesnt matter what is the name of new sheet. I just want to output of code above insert automatically to the new sheet.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to create new sheet and execute that code in new worksheet.

If that is the case try adding following snippet at the beginning of the script

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:= ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
ws.Name = "results"
sheets("results").activate
```